# Djangae - Retrieve GAE user by ID

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am making a simple blog app. A user can log in and create a new post. 
With the post, the `users.get_current_user().user_id()` value is stored under `Post.author_id`. When displaying the post, I want to retrieve the `user.nickname()` using the Post.author_id. Is this possible? Looking at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/userobjects I am not sure how to retrieve a user giving the user_id

p.s I know there is the option to just store the nickname, I am doing this more as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided has a section called "**Using User Values With the Datastore**" where it shows how to retrieve a user with a user_id which should answer your question. Also, to make things simpler - it wouldn't be a bad idea to also have a property `Post.author_nickname` to avoid an extra request to the datastore just for looking up author's nickname.

Comment: The query that is shown is against the Datastore of the example application... The information I am looking for, would not be stored in my database, but instead on a central service that has all the user accounts..